# Caching with core data

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, lru

I inherited some old code where I have an in memory cache without an eviction policy, and the cache is populated once with tens of thousands of different kinds of objects. The memory footprint of the app crosses 500 MB at times, and the app is often terminated due to memory pressure. My question is do I really need a cache over a core data setup? Since core data does the work of loading managed objects into the memory, and evicting them eventually, am I not better off getting rid of this cache which has several arrays and dictionaries holding a lot of objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely avoid a cache on a core data setup. Once objects have been fetched into a managed object context, they are held in memory. Well mostly anyways. So the answer to your question is most likely YES but not knowing the reasons for caching it could also be the opposite. I'd get rid of the cache first and do some performance measurements. Once all scenarios can be confirmed to work fine then the answer was indeed yes.